# Show default custom module section first when open system configuration

Tags: magento, configuration

I want to display custom module configuration when click on system->configuration first.

I have set highest sort order for section but still not display.

My system.xml code look like

```
<tabs>
    <tourtab translate="label" module="customoptioncreater">
        <label>Tour Option Configuration</label>
        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
    </tourtab>
  </tabs>
  <sections>
    <toursection  translate="label" module="customoptioncreater">                    
    <label>Tour Option Configuration</label>
    <tab>tourtab</tab>
    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
    <sort_order>99999</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code you have changed the sort order for **tourtab**. This will display your tab at the first position.

In order to display what you want, change the sort order of your tabs' `<section>`.

```
<tabs>
    <tourtab translate="label" module="customoptioncreater">
        <label>Tour Option Configuration</label>
        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
    </tourtab>
  </tabs>
  <sections>
    <toursection  translate="label" module="customoptioncreater">                    
    <label>Tour Option Configuration</label>
    <tab>tourtab</tab>
    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
```

Now when you click on System > Configuration, your **Tour Option Configuration** tab will be opened first even before Mage's default **General** tab and its sections

Note: You can either change the sort order to 0 or 1.

Comment: I have already set 0 for both tab and section in sort order field.

Comment: Is your Brand Logo tab opening first as shows in screenshot ?

Comment: Check the system.xml of that extension and if it has sort order value less than 10 then change it to something else and give your extension sort order value as 0 or 1 i.e. less than the one specified in Brands system.xml

Comment: brands logo module has 300 sort order.

Comment: ohh sorry i was changed wrong system.xml.actually brandlogo module system.xml has no sort order so i have add sort order for that.and now working.Thanks for your time.

Comment: I recently discovered that the sorting is buggy. Any <section> element with a sort order of 10 or less will cause that section's tab to show up as the displayed section on the page, regardless of the tabs sort order. I tested this in a clean CE 1.7 and a clean EE 1.13. I think it must sort by section, then sort by tab - probably a bad joined table sort in the code.